# run-time error and program crash

Tags: c++

How can I specify a separate function which will be called automatically at Run-Time error to prevent program crash?

Comment: And what do you mean by preventing a program crash?  Bearing in mind that some run-time errors aren't recoverable, what do you want to have happen?

Comment: The correct thing to do in almost every imaginable scenario is to _fix the code such that it doesn't cause a run-time error_.

Comment: @James Unfortunately there are cases where it is neccassary to have some kind of run-time error logging implemented so you are aware of the issues that need to be fixed

Comment: @David:  That may be true, but the intent here is "to prevent program crash."

Answer (score 2):

Best thing as mentioned already is to identify the area where the crash ic occuring and then fix the piece of code. This is the idealistic approach.

In case you are unable to find that out another alternative is to do structured exception handling in the areas where you suspect crashes to occur. Once the crash occurs you capture what ever data you want and process it. Meanwhile you can change the settings in windows service manager to restart your application whenever it crashes. Hope this answers your question.

Also in case you are looking for methods to capture the crash and analyse debugdiag and windbg are some of the standard tools that people use to take the crash dumps.

Comment: OP has mentioned "Program Crash". The windows service manager's restart option helps only if the "Program" is a windows service, I suppose.

Comment: Hmm true. I think we need to wait until the person clarifies if it is a process or a program.

Comment: arpal - It is process(primary thread) crash. The presence of such a function is important in real-time application to recover computer operation in case of unpredictable run-time error.

Comment: You mean to say your process is crashing?

Answer (score 1):

If your in Windows you need to write your own custom runtime check handler.  Use:

```
 _RTC_SetErrorFunc
```

to install your custom function in place of

```
_CrtDbgReport.
```

Here is a good article on how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40ky6s47(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you. Are there any C++ means like set_terminate() function for uncaught exceptins?

Comment: The portable way to do this is to install a signal handler, using the `signal` function from `<csignal>`. This can't be used to recover from a run-time error, however.

Comment: @arpal I am not aware of any C++ means of doing it - However, if it's a RunTime exception then its not a C++ problem - the OS level method is the only way of intervening

Comment: arpal- I do not agree with you. Why C++ provides termination handler function in case of uncaught exception? The same could be done for handling run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

If by run-time error you mean an unhandled exception, **don't do it**.  If an unhanded exception propagates through your code, you *want* your app to crash.  Maybe create a dumpfile on the way down, sure.  But the last thing you want to do is catch the exception, do nothing, and continue running as if nothing had happened in the first place.

When an exception is generated, whatever caused the problem could have had other effects.  Like blowing the stack or corrupting the heap.  If you were to silently ignore these exceptions and continue running anyway, your app might run for a while and seem OK, but something underneath is unstable.  Memory could be corrupt, resources might not be available, who knows.  You will eventually crash.  Bu ignoring unhandled exceptions and running anyway, all you do is delay the inevitable, and make it that much more difficult to diagnose the *real* problem, because when you do crash, the stack will be in a totally different and probably unrelated place from what caused the initial problem.